# ZK paging gui component resize

Tags: java, zk

Is it possible in ZK to alter the height/width component visible at GUI used for navigation?

```
<toolbar>
   <paging id="pagenavi" pageSize="10"  />
   <paging id="pagenavi" pageSize="10" height="50px" width="50px"/>  //something like this
</toolbar>
```

Comment: Can You please explore your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a zk build in way to to it, but you can overwrite the width and height attributes of the css the elements used by the paging element.
[Zk overwriting CSS](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Style%20Guide/ZK%20Class%20Concept/Overwriting)